# Is Mahāyāna Mahāparinirvāṇa Sūtra later creation?

Tags: mahayana

I was thinking to read this big text because the chapter claims to be the teachings of Gautam Buddha while departure from the Earth. Before buying I wanted to be sure whether the text is authentic or not & actually contains last teachings of Gautam Buddha or not. Can anyone shed light on the authenticity of the text Mahāyāna Mahāparinirvāṇa Sūtra?

Comment: I have a somehow long text from a scholar in a (controversial) discussion, but in German - and would not attempt to translate it. Unfortunately I don't find a link using Google only (it sems from a buddhist forum but seemingly not been captured by Google). If you find someone being able to translate I'd put it on some webspace to be accessible. The main line in that comment is that it is of later creation date (than the assumed initial canonization on first council shortly after the death of the Buddha) and also has been subject to various alterations

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I have in PDF in English.

Comment: what does it mean: "I have in PDF in english"? (forgive, I'm not native in english)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I mean I have this sutta in English but not in hardcopy.

Comment: Here, I've even a question based on the text. https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/21126/what-gautam-buddha-said-about-self-in-chapter-three-of-the-mahayana-mahaparin

Comment: For instance a short excerpt on the authenticity of the Sutra by S. Hodge: *"(...) It seems reasonable from the chronological data alone  to  deduce  that  the  MPNS  was  formed  during  the Úâtavâhana  era.  The  Mahâmegha-sûtra,  which  is  a  precursor to the MPNS itself, mentions a Úâtavâhana king  who  was  the  “restorer  of  the  lineage”  and  this
must  be  none  other  than  Gautamîputra  Úâtakarn.i  (r106- 130 CE), (...)* " It is a time ago when I engaged in a discussion about this and cited this (and more) S.Hodge statements, but as well that is mainly in german.

Comment: Ah, Tamas, thanks for the link to the earlier question. What I can contribute are the mentioned (german) comment of the zen scholar(?) Ralf Boeck ("SoGen") in one discussion and my (german) controversial discussion from 2007 but where I have cited some (english) statements of the scholar and translator of the MPNS S. Hodge. I don't like to get involved again into this discussion because it has been -all in all- a much displeasing experience in that mentioned controversy.

Answer (score 1):

I cite here from my older discussion, where I copied&pasted [from a website](http://www.nirvanasutra.org.uk/historicalbackground2.htm) on the MPNS but which possibly does no more exist, didn't check it (but noticed such a remark in a more recent discussion found via google).

*(my original compilation should be findable using google on the newsgroup de.soc.weltanschauung.buddhismus beginning at 10.apr.2007)*

> (...)
>   Historical Background (2)
>   There follows a fascinating, informative and thought-provoking
>   lecture (originally delivered at the University of London, SOAS, in
>   early spring 2006) by Buddhist scholar and translator, Stephen
>   Hodge, on the Tibetan version of the Mahaparinirvana Sutra. I here
>   hand over to Stephen!
>   [S.Hodge]
>   (...)
>   It seems reasonable from the chronological data alone to deduce that
>   the MPNS was formed during the Úâtavâhana era. The Mahâmegha-sûtra,
>   which is a precursor to the MPNS itself, mentions a Úâtavâhana king
>   who was the “restorer of the lineage” and this must be none other
>   than Gautamîputra Úâtakarn.i (r106- 130 CE),
>   (...)
>   Virtually 90% of the remaining text of the MPNS involves this person
>   as the untiring interlocutor who by his questioning draws out of the
>   Buddha a wealth of teachings concerning the permanence of the
>   Buddha, the importance of preserving the authentic Vinaya, the need
>   to purge the San.gha of miscreant monks, the importance of upholding
>   and promulgating the MPNS, and most of all the tathâgata-garbha
>   doctrines. Is it possible that we are hearing the actual voice of a
>   historical individual , called Sarvasattva-priya-darúana by his
>   devoted followers, his words transformed into a sûtra format to
>   ensure the preservation and dissemination of his teachings ?
>   THE ICCHANTIKAS
>   (...) help, who are excluded from this message of hope: a group of
>   people collectively known as the icchantikas - the “extremists”.
>   In the later strata of the text, the MPNS fulminates stridently
>   against these people, repeating statements like
>   “apart from icchantikas, the cause of enlightenment will become
>   present in everybody”
>   or
>   “even those who commit the downfalls or perpetrate the heinous deeds
>   and those who believe that the generation of the aspiration to
>   enlightenment to be unnecessary will be established in the cause of
>   enlightenment - apart from icchantikas who are like death”.
>   So who were these people that the MPNS calls “virulent serpents” ?
>   This question is succinctly answered thus - “any person, no matter
>   whether they are a monk, a nun, a lay-man or lay-woman, who rejects
>   this sûtra with abusive words, and does not even ask for forgiveness
>   afterwards, has entered the icchantika path . . . . Those who have
>   no concern about the
>   (...)
>   And make no mistake about this - the fate of the icchantikas is
>   indeed terrifying, for the sûtra says,
>   “the cause of enlightenment will not be and cannot possibly be
>   engendered in icchantikas”,
>   “they resemble burnt seeds because they have extinguished their
>   wholesome roots”,
>   “the icchantika has no seed and there is no possibility of him
>   having any thought of confessing and begging for forgiveness”.
>   In other words, the MPNS is quite emphatic in its view that these
>   icchantikas will never awaken the potential of their
>   tathâgatagarbha, never achieve liberation and never become Buddhas
>   throughout all eternity.
>   CONCLUSION
>   There is one final twist to the story. As we have seen, the sad-
>   dharma and the bodhisattvas who uphold it were predicted to
>   disappear around 220CE, if our calculations are correct. It seems
>   likely that the MPNS was circulated as the final life- belt for the
>   sinking raft of the Dharma - those who had ears to hear had this
>   last opportunity to save themselves. But what then ? No more
>   authentic Dharma, no more true teachers and no hint here of future
>   Buddha-saviours to come in this corner of sam.sâra. In fact, there
>   is this chilling passage in the MPNS:
>   “Who do not see the goal ? It is the icchantikas who will not see
>   the goal, for they will not see the goal as long as cyclic existence
>   lasts. I have summarized and taught the significance of this, but
>   you should fear what is extremely fearful ! Supposing that all
>   beings in unison were to become fully awakened to supreme and
>   perfect enlightenment, then even if it were possible for the sinful
>   icchantikas to become fully awakened to supreme and perfect
>   enlightenment, they would not see the goal. In that manner, you, o
>   hero, should understand things !
>   “Whose goal does not end in failure ? The Tathâgata's goal does not
>   end in failure. When all beings who dwell in the cycle of existence
>   have become fully awakened to supreme and perfect enlightenment,
>   then the Tathâgata's goal will not have ended in failure and then,
>   having passed into parinirvân.a eternally, the Buddha will become
>   impermanent, like the flame of a lamp whose wick has been consumed.”

Hieran anschließend folgt die Einschätzung:

> in this world - and eventually in the entire universe. Then, those
>   who by definition can never be liberated - the icchantikas - will be
>   left behind to wander lost life-time after lifetime for all
>   eternity. What a bleak scenario !

Comment: So it is very less likely to be the last teachings of Gautam Buddha?

Comment: I also listen Osho almost daily and Read  Krishnamurthy occasionally. Can you suggest me some good enlightening books? :)

Comment: Tamas: I can't speak with authority here, just with common-sense. "Gigantism" - things like the orgiastic large numbers of Arhat & monks at the Parinirvana-event - if it is more than, say, 1000 or 2000 then in my private view result of some sick phantasy and nothing worth to think long about. In the Pali-canon the Buddha is painted as a normal human -who, of course, has achieved high, perhaps the highest, level of enlightnement, but still is a touchable human being,with consent and common sense. -- About Osho, Krishnamurty: I began with the same :) then went to Hakuin, finally Thich Nhat Hanh.

Comment: A book which I value much is that "Cutting the spiritual materialism" although it seems to be somehow "too dry" to be a real "revelation" - anyway I rediscover many thoughts which I was thinking on and found them put in a well and modern way. I liked very very much Osho's books about the (Zen) patriarchs and later the simple but very usable books of Thich Nhat Hanh: "old path, white cloud (...)" and "the heart of the buddha's teaching" .From another approach: that of Sister Chan Khong "Learning true Love". But basically I reread very often the sutras in the Pali-canon online & offline...

Comment: Thanx, will be looking forward to read those books. :)

Comment: I'd add Sri Ramana Maharshi, Sadhguru, Mooji and Rupert Spira. Krishna Prem's commentary on the Bhagavad Gita is wonderful. Philip Kapleau's 'Three Pillars of Zen' is a good read. There are so many good books (and these days videos) that we're spoilt for choice. Nagarjuna's ''Letters of a Friend' might be helpful, or 'Become What You Are' by Alan Watts. There's so much that is good.       ,