# Did the Buddha ever weep in his days of Enlightenment?

Tags: the-buddha, suffering

Did Buddha ever weep while in his days of Enlightenment? What does Buddha say about weeping? Did he ever weep, for instance, a death of a relative?

Comment: Semi-related question: [Did the Buddha ever 'thunder' during a Fire Sermon?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/4117/254)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A Buddha would never ever weep while in his days of Enlightenment. It is because of the quality **Akampita**. It means unshaken; calm; resolute; that which does not tremble; not to be shaken.

The opposite of it is **Kampita** meaning shaken; agitated; quivering; caused to tremble. All these the Buddha was not. A Buddha is always impartial, treating all rivals or disputants equally; fair and just. Other words that describe this quality are unbiased, unprejudiced, neutral, nonpartisan, nondiscriminatory, disinterested, detached, dispassionate, objective, open-minded, equitable. For example the Buddha radiates metta equally towards his adversary Devadatta, Yasodhara his wife, and Patacara the demented woman, his royal father King Suddhodana and Sopaka the humble low-caste youth.

All feelings that arise are due to tanha, or some form of attachment. All such are due to mano sankhara. The feelings, (or the perceptions that give rise to feelings,reside inside oneself. It does not come from outside. We use external things to cause happiness or suffering by our own volition. There is no inherent suffering or happiness in anything external. A Buddha, or for that matter any Arahant, who has removed all asavas, will be free of such emotional responses.

Comment: “This assembly, O bhikkhus, appears indeed empty to me, now that Sariputta and Maha Moggallana have passed away” - Ukkacela Sutta.  Read this as you may but this sounds like grief.